# Is there an application in Windows that lets me share only specific sections of my desktop with multiple users?

Tags: windows, rdp, streaming, screen-sharing

I have a software application on my Windows server with UI that I want to serve to multiple users at the same time without giving them access to other resources on the server.

Ideally only the window of the application is shared with other users having access to that application via mouse interaction. I do not mind which technology is perused (RDP/Streaming/Whatever protocol) as long as only access to that application and its UI is granted but not other resources on the server machine.

Is that possible and does such software application exist?

Comment: Voted to close because asking for product recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for RD Session Host [RemoteApp](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055(v=ws.11).aspx):

> RemoteApp enables you to make programs that are accessed remotely
>   through Remote Desktop Services appear as if they are running on the
>   end user's local computer. These programs are referred to as RemoteApp
>   programs. Instead of being presented to the user in the desktop of the
>   Remote Desktop Session Host (RD Session Host) server, the RemoteApp
>   program is integrated with the client's desktop. The RemoteApp program
>   runs in its own resizable window, can be dragged between multiple
>   monitors, and has its own entry in the taskbar.

Read more about how to use it on article [Configuring RemoteApp Programs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733174(v=ws.11).aspx).